# Angular 2 and Firebase throwing ThenableReference exception on form submit

Tags: forms, angular, firebase

Can you please help me to solve this issue:

```
ERROR in /src/app/services/firebase.service.ts (33,12): Type 'ThenableReference' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'ThenableReference'.)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

My code in service:

```
addBusiness(newBusiness): Promise<any>{
    return this.businesses.push(newBusiness);
  }
```

and codes in component:

```
  addBusiness(
    company:string,
    category:string,
    years_in_business:number,
    description:string,
    phone:string,
    email:string,
    street_address:string,
    city:string,
    state:string,
    zipcode:string
  ){
    var created_at = new Date().toString();

    var newBusiness = {
      company: company,
      category: category,
      years_in_business:years_in_business,
      description:description,
      phone:phone,
      email:email,
      street_address:street_address,
      city:city,
      state:state,
      zipcode:zipcode,
      created_at:created_at
    }
    this._firebaseService.addBusiness(newBusiness);
    this.changeState('default');
  }
```

Comment: Hey , did u manage to solve this ? i have the same problem ?

Answer (score 2):

1. make your `addBusiness` method return `firebase.Thenable` instead of Promise
2. Create a `Promise` object

   ```
   addBusiness(newBusiness): Promise<any>{
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          this.businesses.push(newBusiness)
             .then(x=>resolve(x), x=>reject(x));
      });
   }
   ```